# CSS float:none and margin-right

Tags: css, html, css-float, media-queries

I was just going through some tutorial on responsive web design or fluid layouts.

In the example, a 3-column layout automatically converts to a 2-column layout at lower screen sizes. They have made that possible through 2 CSS properties;

```
float:none
margin-right:0
```

Could you please help me understand how this happens and margin-right is calculated based on what?

Link to example http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

Comment: Maybe you should read the article and look at the examples instead of simply posting it here...

Comment: I want to learn how to build div layouts from scratch..however i have not found any site, which truly explains the building blocks like i know what a float is, what padding,margin means...but do not know how to use them rightly to build a design/layout..Also the site above does not give detailed info on this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article definately is a show you an example of how I do it, so you can take it an adapt it to your particular needs.  You will have to go a step beyond. Hopefully the following explanations and @Wesley's answer will help you do that.

**float:none**

By setting float:none on the elements (that were previously floated), this causes these elements to stack on top of each other *for those sizes of screens*.  The floating perviously caused the elements to line up side-to-side.

**margin-right:0**

In this example, they are setting margin-right:0 so that those imagines line up nicely on the right hand side. If you notice, those images are the ones that are the furthest right *for those sizes of screens*.  If margin-right wasn't set to zero, it would inherit the style of `.figure` which *does* have a margin-right applied.

Comment: Thx..how does margin-right:0 make it align to the right..like generally speaking, how does margin-right know what is the reference point?

Comment: *All* of the other LIs for the images have a margin right, that's what gives you that gutter feel between the images.  If margin-right wasn't zero on the far right one, it would give you either a gutter or would push the image onto the next line (in the case of the ALA article, it pushes it to the next line).  So it doesn't align them to the right, just makes them sit in their correct position. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

The example you linked to contains a thorough explanation of the answer, more than I can provide here. They are using CSS media queries to determine the size of the viewport:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Example in a CSS file:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  .column {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

Example using the `media` attribute of the `<link>` tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
  media="screen and (max-device-width: 480px)"
  href="my-media-specific-stylesheet.css" />
```

> http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/
>
> Thankfully, the W3C created media queries as part of the CSS3
>   specification, improving upon the promise of media types. A media
>   query allows us to target not only certain device classes, but to
>   actually inspect the physical characteristics of the device rendering
>   our work. For example, following the recent rise of mobile WebKit,
>   media queries became a popular client-side technique for delivering a
>   tailored style sheet to the iPhone, Android phones, and their ilk. To
>   do so, we could incorporate a query into a linked style sheet’s media
>   attribute:
>
> The query contains two components:
>
> 1. a media type (screen), and
> 2. the actual query enclosed within parentheses, containing a
>      particular media feature (max-device-width) to inspect, followed by
>      the target value (480px).
>
> In plain English, we’re asking the device if its horizontal resolution
>   (max-device-width) is equal to or less than 480px. If the test
>   passes—in other words, if we’re viewing our work on a small-screen
>   device like the iPhone—then the device will load shetland.css.
>   Otherwise, the link is ignored altogether.